# What are "::operator new" and "::operator delete"?

Tags: c++, new-operator, operator-keyword, delete-operator

I know `new` and `delete` are keywords.

```
int obj = new int;
delete obj;

int* arr = new int[1024];
delete[] arr;
```

`<new>` header is a part of C++ standard headers. It has two operators (I am not sure they are operators or they are functions):

`::operator new`

`::operator delete`

these operators used like below:

```
#include <new>
using namespace std;

int* buff = (int*)::operator new(1024 * sizeof(int));
::operator delete(buff);
```

What are "::operator new" and "::operator delete"? Are they different from `new` and `delete` keywords?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`::` tells the compiler to call the operators defined in global namespace.
It is the fully qualified name for the global `new` and `delete` operators.

Note that one can [replace the global `new` and `delete` operators as well as overload class-specific `new` and `delete` operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421791/452307). So there can be two versions of `new` and `delete` operators in an program. The fully qualified name with the scope resolution operator tells the compiler you are referring to the global version of the operators and not the class-specific ones.

Comment: But programmer should include `new` header.

Comment: @AmirSaniyan The only reason (I know of) to include the new header if is you wish to use [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10)

Comment: @AmirSaniyan: Good Read: [When is #include <new> library required in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788388/when-is-include-new-library-required-in-c)

Comment: @Als As Benj said: if you're using one of the standard placement new's.  Or if you need access to `std::bad_alloc`, or one of the few other functions declared in the header.  It's not needed for the standard non-placement new, regardless of whether you write just `new MyType` or `::new MyType`, and it's not needed if you're `new` expression resolves to a user defined `operator new`, rather than one in the standard library.

Comment: @JamesKanze: True & so i linked the relevant Q as an comment, One of the answers there(not the accepted one) clears this aptly.

Answer (score 26):

the `new` keyword (used alone) is not the same as the `operator new` function.

Calling

```
Object* p = new Object(value);
```

is equvalent in calling

```
void* v = operator new(sizeof(Object));
p = reinterpret_cast<Object*>(v);
p->Object::Object(value); //this is not legal C++, it just represent the implementation effect
```

The operator new (or better the `void* operator new(size_t)` variant) just allocate memory, but does not do any object construction.

The `new` keyword calls the operator new function, but then calls the object constructor.

To separate allocation from contruction, a variant of operator new is declared as

```
void* operator new(size_t, void* at)
{ return at; }
```

and the previous code is typically written as

```
Object* p = reinterpret_cast<Object*>(operator new(sizeof(Object))); //no contruction here
new(p) Object(value); //calls operator new(size_t, void*) via keyword
```

The `operator new(size_t, void*)` does nothing in itself, but, being invoked by the keyword will result in the contructor being called.

Reversely, destruction and deallocation can be separated with

```
p->~Object();
operator delete(p); //no destructor called
```

instead of `delete p`; that calls the destructor and then `operator delete(void*)`.

Answer (score 7):

They are allocator and deallocator functions.  The `new` operator does
two things: it calls an allocator function to get the memory, and it
calls the constructor of the object.  The `delete` operator also does
two things: it calls the destructor, and then calls the a deallocator
function.  The default allocator function is `::operator new`, and the
default deallocator function is `::operator delete`.  Both can be
replaced by the user.

Note that in a new expression, the `::operator new` function is looked
up in more or less the same manner as it would be if it were a normal
function called from within a member function.  As for normal functions,
you can qualify the operator to change the lookup: `new MyClass` will
find a member `operator new` if one is present; `::new MyClass` will use
the default allocator, even if `MyClass` defines a member `operator 
new`.

Comment: +1 for distinguishing between the allocation function and the *new-expression*. Both use the `new` keyword in their syntax.

Answer (score 3):

`::` means just a global namespace

Comment: when `new` is a keyword, why should I use global namespace?

Comment: You shouldn't it's show that you are using new from global namespace. But you can override your new version then you will use your namespace if you need