# Why std::allocator<T>::allocate calls ::operator new?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, new-operator, allocator

The documentation for the `std::allocator<T>::allocate` member function says in ([[allocator.members]](https://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.members)) that:

> *Remarks*: **The storage for the array is obtained by calling ​`::​operator new`** ([new.delete]), but it is unspecified when or how often this function is called. This function starts the lifetime of the array object, but not that of any of the array elements.

I wonder why it says `::operator new` and not just `operator new`? Does the double colon make any difference? Which other `operator new` could be called here, if that double colon was omitted?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10513443/1570854

Comment: @Lesiak I can understand that, in general, we sometimes need to distinguish between the global and class-specific `operator new`. But how is this related to `std::allocator`?

Comment: `new` is an operator, and as such is subject to the rules of ADL like other operators.  By using `::operator new` the ADL gets bypassed and only the global new defined by the compiler, or the global new you have replaced it with, will be used.

Comment: @NathanOliver I understand that. But I don't know which other possible `operator new` could be selected by ADL here than that global one (compiler-defined or replaced)?

Comment: Classes can overload `operator new`.  If they did so and `allocate` just used `new T` then you would get that class overload of new instead of the global new.  `::operator new` stops that from happening even if the class overloads `new`

Comment: @NathanOliver How can `std::allocator<T>::allocate` use `new T`? It should just allocate and not initialize any objects of type `T`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @DanielLangr Sorry, should have said if they used `operator new`, and now that I say that I get your confusion.  They would have to use `T::operator new` to get the class new.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Prior to [LWG2818](https://wg21.link/LWG2818), [[contents]p3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/contents#3) read:

> Whenever a name `x` defined in the standard library is mentioned, the name `x` is assumed to be fully qualified as `::std::x`, unless explicitly described otherwise. For example, if the *Effects*: element for library function `F` is described as calling library function `G`, the function `::std::G` is meant.

So writing `operator new` in the specification would mean `::std::operator new`, which wouldn't make sense. `::operator new` correctly refers to `operator new` in the global namespace.

In an implementation of the standard library, there would be no difference between writing `operator new` and `::operator new` since `std::allocator<T>` wouldn't define a member `operator new` and ADL has no effect since there is only one namespace a free `operator new` could be defined in.

Comment: It is exactly the explanation I was looking for. Thanks! I didn't know about this rule and learnt something new today.