# Why does the implicit declaration does not introduce the name?

Tags: c++

I've read the following two earlier questions,but still can't have a good undertanding.
1. [Why do I need to #include  when using the typeid operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704978/why-do-i-need-to-include-typeinfo-when-using-the-typeid-operator)
2. [When is #include  library required in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788388/when-is-include-new-library-required-in-c/2788548#2788548)

Since the `typeid` uses the `type_info` class,it's reasonable to require us `#include<typeinfo>`.
However,**the `new operators` also uses `std::bad_alloc` ,why does it not require us to `#include <new>`?**  ( I know that `sizeof()` does not require `<cstddef>` because the `size_t` coulde be replaced with built-in types during compile time,as long as the compiler knows what the `size_t` actually is. )

According to the most-voted answer in the 2th question,he says:

> Note: **the implicit declarations do not introduce the names std, std::bad_alloc, and std::size_t**, or any other names that the library uses to declare these names. Thus, a newexpression, delete-expression or function call that refers to one of these functions without including the header is well-formed. However, referring to std, std::bad_alloc, and std::size_t is ill-formed unless the name has been declared by including the appropriate header.

The paragraph above is confusing,since everytime we use a type,we need to declare a type before usage like `class A;void foo(A*);`And the **implicit declaration** of `void* operator new(std::size_t) throw(std::bad_alloc);`also has a type `std::bad_alloc` ,is it a privilege for the **implicit declaration** to not declare the type it use?

Comment: Some types are builtin to the compiler...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Is it just because the _c++ standard_ told us to do?

Comment: Not necessarily. IIRC a compiler might predefine some types with a name starting with `_` (they are reserved to the implementation) and some headers might `typedef` these names into a name mentioned in the standard

Comment: The standard tells *us* how to write programs. The standard also tells *compiler writers* what programs their implementation should accept or reject. If you use `std::bad_alloc` without including an appropriate header, the implementation should reject your program *because the standard told the compiler writer to do so*.

Comment: The other question is pretty old, and [the declaration of `operator new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) hasn't mentioned `bad_alloc` for several revisions of the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward declaration is used for *name lookup*. For the implicit declarations, the compiler already knows the semantic of these names, so it does not need to perform name lookup, thus a forward declaration (i.e. the header) is needless.

The key is that `void foo(A*);` is written by **you**, so you must tell the compiler what `A` is via a forward declaration, while the implicit declaration is written by the **compiler**, so you needn't tell the complier what the names used in the declaration are.

Note the reasons above are not sufficient to explain why `<typeinfo>` is required before any use of `typeid`. In fact, this rule is explicitly stated in the standard [[expr.typeid] paragraph 6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.typeid#6):

> If the header `<typeinfo>` is not included prior to a use of `typeid`, the program is ill-formed.