# Why isn't placement new keyword/operator/function recognised without header?

Tags: c++, new-operator

In the following:

```
int main()
{
    new int; // Works
    
    
    int* pmem = 0;

    new (pmem) int;// Doesn't recognize new keyword/operator/function???

}
```

It won't recognise 'new' in this case without including the < iostream > header. Why is that? Why doesn't 'new' require a header but placement new does? If 'new' requires a function to be defined then why does 'int* a = new int;' work? Since it's not defined anywhere, I assumed it's part of the language. However 'new (&int) int;' 'placement new' isn't part of the language?

Visual Studio gives error:

> 'operator new': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments

Comment: I wouldn't even rely on that. Placement new is provided by mandate when you include `<new>` . That it "works" for you when you include `<iostream>` is a symptom, not a cure. The regular forms of `operator new` that you are familiar with are [implicitly available](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) by standard mandate

Comment: Relevant [When is #include <new> library required in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788388/when-is-include-new-library-required-in-c)

Comment: That is not actually a duplicate. While relevant, it is asking (and answering) a different question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Placement new isn't just for "no-op" allocation. It's a general term for providing extra arguments to `new` beyond the object size. A standard example would be `std::nothrow`.

Since we are providing arguments, the compiler has to do overload resolution to choose an appropriate `operator new` function. And that means that overloads must be declared beforehand. The most basic overload is implicitly declared (in a way), while `void* operator new(std::size_t, void* ptr) noexcept` (the [standard library function](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/new.delete.placement) that does this "allocation") is not. So we must include the header (`<new>`*) for overload resolution.

That was the design choice made 30 years ago. It could have been done by another built-in, but since placing objects into pre-allcoated raw storage is deemed a pretty advanced feature (as opposed to simple dynamic allocation), adding a library dependency probably didn't seem like much of a hindrance.

---

* - You saw `<iostream>` affecting the behavior because it probably includes `<new>` either directly or indirectly. It's permissible, but not required behavior.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around this. new is mentioned as an operator, but it very much looks like an overloaded function call. I call new (pToMem) obj{ }; And it's as if the first argument of size_t is implicitly provided. Is it a function call whereas the the ordinary new is an operator?

Comment: `new T` is an expression. Part of its evaluation involves calling a function (`operator new`). That's always true. The unintuitive bit is that one function is always implicitly declared. This is because simple dynamic allocation is pretty basic thing used in many programs. Other forms of the `new` expression require an explicit declaration.

Comment: I can never a constructor myself, right? So if I want to construct an object at memory I want, say in my container, this is the only way I can do that, placement new, and I need to include the header, right?

Comment: Yes. That's accurate.

Comment: But why doesn't the compiler need to do overload resolution to call `void* operator new(std::size_t)` when you do `new int;`?

Comment: @Joseph - Who says it doesn't? It may, or it may not do overload resolution. It may implicitly declare the function, or it may hard code a call to it sometimes. It works like that because the standard says so. Just like it's possible to "replace" those allocation functions (despite no other free functions supporting such a thing). It's simply how the behavior is defined.